# Check OneDrive and OneNote clients status with PowerShell (or other script solution)

Tags: powershell, onedrive, onenote

I'd like to get the status of my **OneDrive** and my **OneNote** **clients** installed on my workstation (*UpToDate, Syncing, Error, etc.*) with a PowerShell script running in the background to monitor and force syncing if necessary.

I found several subjects about doing this on many forums, but nothing correctly answering my problem. The best I found is an open source library (https://github.com/rodneyviana/ODSyncService) which allows to obtain the status of OneDrive with a PowerShell cmdlet (*Get-ODStatus*) but I can not install it on my workstation and it does not manage the access to the status of OneNote.

Is there a way to reliably get the value of the status of OneDrive and OneNote clients with PowerShell or other scripting language ? Is there a better way to do this ? Maybe with the OneDrive API (I read quickly the documentation but did not found what I'm looking for) ?

Thanks for your answers.